# python dictionary keys not accessible in app engine

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, dictionary

this is driving me crazy. I'm new to both python and AppEngine, and I can't seem to figure this out. I am writing a simple app hosted by the App Engine. My problem is: I can access a python dictionary with a for loop, but I cannot access items in the dictionary directly using a key string.

I'm calling a JSON web service that returns the following JSON string:

```
{"WA": "Washington", "DE": "Delaware", "DC": "District of Columbia", "WI": "Wisconsin", "WV": "West Virginia", "HI": "Hawaii", "FL": "Florida", "WY": "Wyoming", "NH": "New Hampshire", "NJ": "New Jersey", "NM": "New Mexico", "TX": "Texas", "LA": "Louisiana", "NC": "North Carolina", "ND": "North Dakota", "NE": "Nebraska", "TN": "Tennessee", "NY": "New York", "PA": "Pennsylvania", "CA": "California", "NV": "Nevada", "VA": "Virginia", "CO": "Colorado", "AK": "Alaska", "AL": "Alabama", "AR": "Arkansas", "VT": "Vermont", "IL": "Illinois", "GA": "Georgia", "IN": "Indiana", "IA": "Iowa", "MA": "Massachusetts", "AZ": "Arizona", "ID": "Idaho", "CT": "Connecticut", "ME": "Maine", "MD": "Maryland", "OK": "Oklahoma", "OH": "Ohio", "UT": "Utah", "MO": "Missouri", "MN": "Minnesota", "MI": "Michigan", "RI": "Rhode Island", "KS": "Kansas", "MT": "Montana", "MS": "Mississippi", "SC": "South Carolina", "KY": "Kentucky", "OR": "Oregon", "SD": "South Dakota"}
```

The python codes is as follow:

```
states=dict()

url="http://something.com/json"
try:
   response=urllib2.urlopen(url)
   states=json.load(response)
except Exception as ex:
   self.response.write("Google says: %s"%(ex.message))
   self.response.write("<br>Try refreshing the page again")
   SystemExit(0)
```

This is where it gets confusing. The following statement execute just fine:

```
for each in states:
  self.response.write(states[each])
  self.response.write("<br>")
  self.response.write(each)
  self.response.write("<br>")
```

But I need to refer to the dictionary using its key. So, I did this:

```
self.response.write(states["IN"])
```

This doesn't work. Google is saying:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/bu3245/1.371010709629673028/test.py", line 42, in get
self.response.write(states["IN"])
KeyError: 'IN'
```

What did I do wrong?
When i debug locally, the code works, but it doesn't work when it's on the app engine. I can see all the keys and the value spit out by the for loop, but if I access the dictionary using its key, it will tell me key error. If i try using integer as the index, it will say KeyError as well.

Comment: Try `for abbr, state in states:`

Comment: i can get it to work in for loop with no problem. My problem is i cannot directly access the dictionary using it's key like     
`states["IN"]`. I just fond out that it would work using the get method. So, if i do `states.get("IN")`. It would work. this is crazy!!!

Comment: Are you sure "IN" is contained within states?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access a dictionary by index because it will think you are trying to access the dictionary with a key with value of that index.

I believe `.get()` works for you because even when the key does not exist in the dictionary, `.get()` will return `None` and thus will not crash your app.

Make sure when you deploy that "IN" is indeed within the response.

Similar to @karthikr said, it's usually better to iterate through dictionary by:

```
for key, value in dictionary.iteritems()
```